# spring rabbit listen only one output queue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a web application, called router. This app sends messages to X MQ queues. But I want to do it not dependent on number of queues, I want it to listen only on one output queue, so it will send to X queues, but consumers will send results to one queue. Is it possible? How to set up corellationIds properly?

Comment: If router needs to send messages to X queues but without the knowledge of these X queues, you could use a fanout exchange.

Comment: Thank you,I need to send the message to the X certain queues, I know their names, and will send it by name. But consumers will put the results to the ONE output queue, should I take care about corellationIds in this case? Thank you

Comment: In other words, I have Y queues, but need to send to X<=Y only, by names

Comment: You should only take care about correlation id if you need to correlate the response with the request. If the response if self sufficient, correlation id is useless.